# No route matches [POST] for edit form - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**im using rails 5**

i have a model named **Prices**. (has_many **products**)

**Prices** has a model named **Product** (belongs_to **price**)

In this case i can create new **product** and also can destroy **product**.
but i cannot edit the **product**.

> my routes

```
  resources :prices do
    resources :products
  end
```

> in my price show

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_price_product_path(product.price, product) %>
```

> in my product edit

```
<%= form_for @product, :url => {:action => :edit}, :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name' %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

> in my product controller

```
def edit
end

def update
    product.update(product_params)
    if @product.update(product_params)
        redirect_to price_path(@price)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

**My rake routes**

```
price_products GET    /prices/:price_id/products(.:format)          products#index
                         POST   /prices/:price_id/products(.:format)          products#create
     new_price_product GET    /prices/:price_id/products/new(.:format)      products#new
    edit_price_product GET    /prices/:price_id/products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
         price_product GET    /prices/:price_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#show
                         PATCH  /prices/:price_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                         PUT    /prices/:price_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                         DELETE /prices/:price_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
```

> The Problem is
>
> when i click submit button, i got this error

```
No route matches [POST] "/price/price_id/product/product_id/edit"
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**namespaced syntax**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-namespaces) to deal with your nested resource:

```
<%= form_for [:price, @product] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry one more question.. in my update controller i have redirect_to price_path(@price), but when i edit the product i got this error  >> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"prices", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id].. But it worked great if i change to redirect_to root_path... thanks for helping

Comment: @Dhaniel in products_controller, set `@price = Price.find(params[:price_id])` in update (check your logs to see the param returned on click update but it should be price_id)

Comment: thx for reply me.. i still got this error.. and in my url show this urlhttp://localhost:3000/prices/product_id/products/product_id

Comment: http://localhost:3000/prices/product_id(i think i got error on this part)/products/product_id